# How to Delete an Empty Section After moveRowAt: sourceIndexPath:?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

After dragging a row into a new section, if the source section is empty, how do I delete this section?

My code:

```
var exerciseSets = [Array<Exercise>]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.exerciseSets.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let set = self.exerciseSets[section]
        return set.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        var sourceSet = self.exerciseSets[sourceIndexPath.section]
        let sourceExercise = sourceSet[sourceIndexPath.row]

        var destinationSet = self.exerciseSets[destinationIndexPath.section]
        destinationSet.insert(sourceExercise, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

        sourceSet.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        if sourceSet.count == 0 {
            self.exerciseSets.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.section)
        }
    }
```

`exerciseSets` has an array of `Exercise` objects to populate the rows of each section. When a cell is moved, I update the data source, remove a section (from `exerciseSets` array) if its now empty.

If a section is empty and data source is updated to reflect the reduced number of sections, I am still left with an empty section on screen. Reloading the tableView in `moveRowAt` crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to implement a minimal working example to test out how it all works. Following is a working example, that indeed uses `deleteSections` as I have recommended before:

```
import UIKit

class Table: UITableViewController {

    var excerciseSets: [[String]] = [
        ["Mama", "Tato", "Baba"],
        ["1", "2", "3"],
        ["a", "b", "c"],
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return excerciseSets.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return excerciseSets[section].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = excerciseSets[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return "Family"
        case 1:
            return "Numbers"
        case 2:
            return "Letters"
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        var sourceSet = self.excerciseSets[sourceIndexPath.section]
        let sourceExercise = sourceSet[sourceIndexPath.row]

        var destinationSet = self.excerciseSets[destinationIndexPath.section]
        destinationSet.insert(sourceExercise, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

        sourceSet.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

        // I had to update sets back, because an array of value types acts like a value type
        // when I created variables destinationSet and sourceSet, arrays were copied, therefore
        // so far I haven't really changed the model in self.excerciseSets
        self.excerciseSets[destinationIndexPath.section] = destinationSet
        self.excerciseSets[sourceIndexPath.section] = sourceSet

        if sourceSet.count == 0 {
            self.excerciseSets.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.section)

            // Remove the section
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteSections([sourceIndexPath.section], with: .none)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

Now notice especially these lines in `moveRowAt`:

```
// I had to update sets back, because an array of value types acts like a value type
// when I created variables destinationSet and sourceSet, arrays were copied, therefore
// so far I haven't really changed the model in self.excerciseSets
self.excerciseSets[destinationIndexPath.section] = destinationSet
self.excerciseSets[sourceIndexPath.section] = sourceSet
```

Before I realized that the model is not being really updated, there have been some weird behavior. If your model (`Exercise`) is a `struct`, it is also a value type, and by moving rows around you are not really updating the model behind unless you reassign the arrays back.

Go over your code and check if that is not the case.

Comment: I have tried this with the `sectionIndex` being `sourceIndexPath.section`, in the if statement, but this also crashes.

Comment: @JoshKahane what's the crash? can you add crash log?

Comment: On `endUpdates()` I get the following crash: `Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]` – `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).`

Comment: @JoshKahane I am a bit guessing here right now, but try the updated code.. If it won't work, I will later look at it but I have some work right now (maybe in an hour)..

Comment: No luck, I see what we were trying but unfortunately provides the same result. This is quite the oddity.

Comment: @JoshKahane how does `Exercise` class look? is it a class or a struct?

Comment: @JoshKahane I have updated my answer with a minimal working example - for me that code works just fine. Check my comment at the end of the question, maybe that's your problem. Otherwise you will have to give us a bit more code to find what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163010/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-josh-kahane).

Comment: Well blow me down, that resolved the issue. `Exercise` is just a subclass of `NSObject` so I figured it wouldn't be an issue and that all pointers would work themselves out. Updating the arrays worked! Many thanks for your time Milan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this at end of **moveRowAt**

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the section header height to zsro instead of actually deleting the section.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if list.isEmpty {
            return 0
        }


        return 42
    }
```